# Set default query string in Guzzle 6

Tags: php, guzzle

After upgrading to Guzzle6, I can't figure out how to setup default query string for the Client.

I have the following:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client( [
    'base_uri' => 'http://api.example.org/',
    'query'   => ['key' => 'secretKey']
] );
$client->get( 'extract', ['query' => ['url' => $url]] );
```

In this request my default query sting `key=secretKey` is being ignored.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 6):

Guzzle v6 does not support default query strings within the client options. Middleware is required.

```
$handler = new HandlerStack();
$handler->setHandler(new CurlHandler());

//Add access token
$handler->unshift(Middleware::mapRequest(function(RequestInterface $request) {
    return $request->withUri(Uri::withQueryValue($request->getUri(), 'key', 'value'));
}));

//Create client
$this->client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => ''
    'handler' => $handler
]);
```

See https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1138 for source.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to get default 'query' options using 'getConfig' method and then merge them with new  'query' options, here an example:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'base_uri' => 'http://api.example.org',
    'query'   => ['key' => 'secretKey']
]);
```

And then you can easy send a GET request:

```
$client->get('/extract', [
    'query' =>  array_merge(
        $client->getConfig('query'),
        ['url' => $url]
     )
]);
```

Additional info you can find here [Request Options](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/request-options.html#request-options)